# Low resolution RenderTexture with gradients

Tags: unity, rendering, rendertexture

I have a small RenderTexture that stretched on large object, so texels is near 0.3 of unit. Source for this texture has much more resolution and with gradients.

If source little bit changes its brightness, camera renders it much different.
[On this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIqW1gcBpPw), first is source, second is texture. Also the rendered gradient is not constant.

How can I fix it?

[Archive with minimal scene](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bpCX6Lm3_ZoBYoPp2IFLDgqwGpdGsv2I) - If you hide source object in inspector and move it, you will see artifacts on result object.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me from the video what you're trying to do. Please edit your question to walk us through the steps we need to take to reproduce this problem in a new empty project, so we can see directly what's happening and test solutions to make sure they work correctly.

Comment: @DMGregory I added a project with minimal scene.

Comment: Please post instructions, not a file that a user has to download and trust.

Comment: @DMGregory wow! [Do you trust in github](https://github.com/artygrand/RenderTextureTest)?

Comment: The problem with external links is that they can rot, or their contents can change in a way that renders your question unclear for future readers. This is why we require questions about debugging to include *in their body text* a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example that does not depend on files hosted elsewhere.